# Creating multiple arrays dynamically in C/Fortran based on loop iterator

Tags: c, loops, fortran

I want to create multiple arrays based on the iterations of a loop in C.

For example:

```
int i, size;

for ( i =0; i< 10; i++)
{
  size = i * 100
  create_array(i,size); // This loop iterates 9 times creating 9 different arrays
}

void create_array(int name, int size)
{
  double *array_name = (double*) malloc (size*sizeof(double));
  // perform operations on array_name

}
```

Therefore we end up with 9 arrays namely array_0,array_1, .... array_9.
Can this be accomplished in C or Fortran (not C++)?

Comment: You are not returning `array_name` from `create_array`. Where do you want to have array_0, array_1 etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Fortran example:

```
program create_arrays


type ArrayHolder_type
   integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: IntArray
end type ArrayHolder_type

type (ArrayHolder_type), dimension (:), allocatable :: Arrays

integer :: i, j

allocate ( Arrays (4) )

do i=1, 4
   allocate ( Arrays (i) % IntArray (2*i) )
end do

do i=1, 4
   do j=1, 2*i
      Arrays (i) % IntArray (j) = i+j
   end do
   write (*, *)
   write (*, *) i
   write (*, *) Arrays (i) % IntArray
end do


end program create_arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of arrays?

```
double *arrays[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    arrays[i] = malloc(some_size * sizeof(double));
```

Now you have an array of "arrays", conveniently named `arrays[0]` to `arrays[9]`.

---

If you want the amount of arrays to be dynamic as well, use double-pointer:

```
double **arrays;

arrays = malloc(number_of_arrays * sizeof(double *));

/* Allocate each sub-array as before */
```

Comment: typo mistake in second `malloc()` `,` instead of `*`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but  instead of having the name array_0,array_1, .... array_9. 
you will have a like Matrix ( you can acces to your arrays array[1], array[2]...) by doing this

```
    int i, size;

double ** array = (double**) malloc (size*sizeof(double*));
for ( i =0; i< 10; i++)
{
  size = i * 100
  array[i] = create_array(size); 
}

double* create_array( int size)
{
  double *array_name = (double*) malloc (size*sizeof(double));
  // perform operations on array_name;
  return arrayname;

}
```